# Python: Map float range [0.0, 1.0] to color range [red, green]?

Tags: python, colors, range

I have a function that returns float results in the interval [0.0, 1.0]. I would like to visualize the results using color ranging from red for 0.0 to green for 1.0 (maybe through yellow for 0.5). How could I do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the simplest way is to work in [HSL/HSB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) (hue saturation lightness), where the hue values 0-33% of the maximum will map to the range red-orange-yellow-green.  The advantage of working is HSL (vs RGB) is that the resulting color range will be much better-looking (eg bright yellow in RGB contains a pinch of blue).

So basically you will create a value based on a constant S and L value, and a H that corresponds to

```
your_value * (1/3 of the maximum H value, often 255)
```

and then transform that value back to RGB for display.  Don't know Python (shame on me) but apparently the [colorsys module](http://effbot.org/librarybook/colorsys.htm) can do this transformation for you.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a way to present RGB values represented as 3-tuples (R,G,B) in the range of 0..1, it sounds like you want to go from: (1, 0, 0)  to: (0, 1, 0).

You can just use:  `rgbs = [(1-i,i,0) for i in your_floats]`

Then use any graphics library to visualize these 3-tuples as actual RGB colors.

Comment: I just checked on the color wheel on Paint, this gives super muddy values when you get far from i=1 or i=0. To have a nice and bright color you want to stay on the outside of the circle, so RGB=(1,0,0) then (1,1,0) then (0,1,0).